# is there a way to get an outline on my toon-model without duplicating the mesh

Tags: shaders, toon-shading

question says it all. i want to give an outline to my toon meshes without needing to duplicate the mesh, make a black material, expand the mesh (with alt+s), and then invert normals. is there a way?

what i currently have:

[image: showing model with outline mesh selected]

[image: showing what the outline mesh looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally do this using a solidifier modifier instead of duplicating and scaling the mesh, tends to be a bit easier when animating too. Super important that if you do it this way you remember to keep backface culling on on the outline material.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've gotten some rather decently fast renders when using the outline method like this, it might also affect speed where you place your modifier in the stack whether it would be above or below the Armature modifier! Try out yourself and see what works best for you and your machine ;)

Comment: im getting some artifacts. is there a way to get rid of those?
https://imgur.com/a/DtSOqqU

Comment: Try messing around with the thickness of the solidifier that can help, it will be a lot of picking your angles however, that's just the nature of outlines as far as I know :)

Comment: this is for viewport renders? what if I wanna use cycles?